# How to change date format before resolving GET request

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

On my model, I default the `dateOrdered` object as Date.now()

```
dateOrdered: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
```

I want to format this `dateOrdered` using moment.js before resolving the request. Please take a look.

```
ordersRouter.route('/getorders')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        Orders.find()
            .populate({ path: 'userPurchased products.product', select: '-username -password' })
            .exec(function (err, orders) {
                var fromNow = moment(orders.dateOrdered).fromNow();
                var cleanDate = moment(orders.dateOrdered).format('MMM Do YYYY');

                orders.dateOrdered = cleanDate;

                res.json(orders);
            });
    });
```

How can I format this to make it in an understandable format? Here's what it looks like now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`moment(orders.dateOrdered).format('MMM Do YYYY')` returns a string, not a Date. The Mongoose Schema casts the string back to a proper Date object when you assign it, and that Date is then being serialized as a default-format timestamp. Hence the ugly date string in the rendered output.

Try:

```
orders = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orders));
orders.dateOrdered = cleanDate;
res.json(orders);
```

Here we have converted from Schema to vanilla types to avoid the casting.